# Sticky Footer CSS HTML in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, sticky-footer

Please check over the site: [www.HearMe.fm](http://www.HearMe.fm)

As you can see, there is a sticky on the bottom of the page. The problem is that I want the bottom of the page extended, so that the content is not hidden under the sticky element. I.e. the left hand menu is covered by the sticky bar.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. You know, you could have been useful and actually answered the question

Comment: Only answer questions that conform with the rules of the site. My comment above is an exact copy of a close reason.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#headerwrap {
    z-index: 9999999999;
}
```

Comment: Not quite the desired behaviour, but I can work with that